# VB 2010: About _CheckedChanged

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkbox

```
Private Sub OpTest_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpArhein.CheckedChanged
    configSave()
    MsgBox("OpTest changed.")

End Sub
```

The CheckBox is set to start as checked. When I Start Debugging this runs and this MsgBox pops up, yet the MsgBox within configSave() does not. configSave() is defined before this.

While debugging, if I uncheck or check the CheckBox then both MsgBox come up fine.

Why is this running at start up?
How should I go about preventing it from running at start up?
I plan on having 48 CheckBoxes so having it run 48 times at start up seems extremely unnecessary.

As you can probably tell, I'm extremely new to this. So thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you change the value of property Checked of this control during form_load?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues in the past and actually ended up handling the `Checked` event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub OpTest_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles OpArhein.CheckedChanged
```

This is a VB.NET specific quirk, it doesn't happen in C# projects.  It is caused by the *Handles* keyword in your code.  It causes the event to be subscribed too early.  The event handler runs when the checkbox is initialized by the form constructor.  Too early.

The workaround is to subscribe it later.  Delete the `Handles OpArhein.CheckChanged` clause and add a constructor to your form.  Make it look like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler OpArhein.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OpTest_CheckedChanged
End Sub
```

The AddHandler statement does the same thing as the Handles keyword but does it explicitly.  And lets you determine exactly *when* the event gets subscribed.  Doing it after the InitializeComponent() call solves your problem.

Comment: Now that's interesting! No wonder I couldn't reproduce it with C# code :)